# How to USE following CURL command in java?

Tags: java, android, curl-commandline

This is the URL

*curl -H "Authorization: Bearer oVi4yPxk1bJ64Y2qOsLJ2D2ZlC3FpK4L" https://api.url.com/v1/market/total-items.json*

I want to use it on JAVA where *oVi4yPxk1bJ64Y2qOsLJ2D2ZlC3FpK4L*  value will be a dynamic value which i receive using a variable.

Comment: Curl is a bash command, you need to implement a GET and/or POST to do your request. You can use a library or do it your self. See Retrofit or Volley, there are good library.

Comment: add `"Authorization: Bearer oVi4yPxk1bJ64Y2qOsLJ2D2ZlC3FpK4L"` to your header. Key is `Authorization` and value is `Bearer oVi4yPxk1bJ64Y2qOsLJ2D2ZlC3FpK4L`

Comment: Could you provide me sample php code for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in Java. 
curl - h is taken care by httpPost.addHeader()
curl - d by the form body
curl -u at least in the case of this API (e.g stripe) it was the authorization Bearer. In case of Oauth2, curl -u is passing username:password in the header e.g

```
form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", request.getParameter("username")));

CloseableHttpClient userWebTokenHTTPclient;
        if (HIFIConstants.FULL_URL_HIFINITE.contains("localhost")) {  //for localhost HTTP request fails due to certificate issues, hence workaround. Works for Beta etc without SSLContext

            SSLContextBuilder sslcontext = new SSLContextBuilder();
            sslcontext.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
            userWebTokenHTTPclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslcontext.build()).setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                    .build();
        } else
            userWebTokenHTTPclient = HttpClients.createDefault();



        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://api.somepublicsite.com/v1/ident/verits");

        List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
        form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("return_url", "https://example-dev.example.com?vi={VERIFICATION_INTENT_ID}"));
        form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requested_verifications[0]", "identity_document"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, Consts.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer somesecretkeyhere"); 
        httpPost.addHeader("Version", "v3");
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");    
        CloseableHttpResponse tokenResponse = userWebTokenHTTPclient.execute(httpPost);
        org.json.JSONObject verificationIntent = new org.json.JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(tokenResponse.getEntity()));
        userWebTokenHTTPclient.close();
```